# How Arrays.toString() works for Object Arrays

Tags: java

```
// Java program to demonstrate working of Arrays.toString()
// for user defined objects.
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

// Driver class
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Student [] arr = {new Student(111, "bbbb", "london"),
                          new Student(131, "aaaa", "nyc"),
                          new Student(121, "cccc", "jaipur")};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }    
}

// A class to represent a student.
class Student
{
    int rollno;
    String name, address;

    // Constructor
    public Student(int rollno, String name,
                               String address)
    {
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    // Used to print student details in main()
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.rollno + " " + this.name +
                           " " + this.address;
    }
}
```

Output of the above code is:
[111 bbbb london, 131 aaaa nyc, 121 cccc jaipur]

My question is what actually happens in the line:
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));?

Does Arrays.toString(arr) call toString method of each Student Object or something like that?

Comment: You can just look at the code for `Arrays.toString()` to see what it does.

Comment: Or just look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-) for it. Always perform adequate research *before* asking a question here.

Comment: Or simply think about it as you have your input and output. Some logical thinking and you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

> Does Arrays.toString(arr) call toString method of each Student Object or something like that?

Yes, you are right. Every object inherits from the Object which has `toString()` method and `Arrays.toString()` calls it for each of the object. However in most of cases it returns the object reference string by default. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-):

> If the array contains other arrays as elements, they are converted to strings by the Object.toString() method inherited from Object

The idea is to `@Override` this method and customize the output.